# Magnetization Inductance vs. Transformer Inductance

Tags: transformer, inductance, magnetics

what is the difference between transformer inductance and magnetization inductance, as I know transformer inductance is calculated with magnetization current but I've never seen magnetization inductance calculation.

Comment: Same thing for any normal transformer.

Comment: *"I've never seen magnetization inductance calculation"* It's very common. In radio electronics, because a transformer has magnetizing inductance, it's often used as an inductor - just add capacitors, it becomes an LC circuit, and the turn-ratio of the transformer converts the impedance for the next stage.

Comment: I "remember" that Lm was calculated for eliminating the "ideal transformer" in an equivalent schematic without transformer ... but it was a long time ago ... It seems to me that measuring is done by measuring "input impedance" while secondary is shorted. ? To be verified ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The transformer primary, in the absence of a load on the secondary, is just an inductor and, as with any inductor, the current that passes through it causes magnetization hence, the current that flows into the transformer primary with no secondary load is basically the magnetization current.

It's probably better if you looked at the equivalent circuit of a power transformer: -

[image]

\$L_P\$ and \$L_S\$ are inductances that don't couple between primary and secondary aka leakage inductance.

> *I've never seen magnetization inductance calculation.*

I've literally seen dozens and dozens - it's probably one of the first calculations you make when designing a transformer. You have the core material and dimensions and from that you can calculate inductance based on \$A_L\cdot N^2\$ where \$A_L\$ is a number that embodies all the core and dimensional data and \$N\$ is the number of turns.

Comment: sorry it's my bad, confused about so much things, I've also calculated that before, so much inductances for a new starter on transformers.

Comment: Is this a good tool ? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.avglab.transcalc&hl=en_US&gl=US

Comment: @Antonio51 I have no idea. Why don't you download it and compare it with an already worked-out solution elsewhere on the web.